# DB2 connectivity from Python - ibm_db.connect time out / latency

Tags: python, db2

I am trying to connect to DB2 data base ; Read it from once table and insert in to another table. ( Both tables are in same DB and schema ) .

As part of that , I am trying to print first table contents. I don't see any errors but python script is running for long time and not printing first line `"connection succesful"`

```
import ibm_db

conn = ib_db.connect ("DATABASE=SOADB;HOSTNAME=xxxxxx;PORT=1234;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=uuu;PWD=xxx;", "", "")

print ("connection succesful")    
sql = "select * from ABC.TABLE fetch first 50 rows only ;"    
stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,sql)    
tuple=ibm_db.fetch_tuple(stmt)

while tuple:
    print(tuple)tuple=ibm_db.fetch_tuple(stmt)
```

Comment: Please post the full error that you are getting, as well as a description of what you are attempting to do in english.

Comment: I am trying to connect to DB2 data base ; Read it from once table and insert in to another table. ( Both tables are in same DB and schema ) . As part of that , i am trying to print first table contents.  I don't see any errors but python script is running for long time and not printing first line "connection succesful'

Comment: So the script does nothing? It never completes? Are you local or remote to the DB2 database (i.e., connected by LAN)? Do be aware: DB2 is available for desktops and mainframe computers. Be sure appropriate drivers are set up.

Comment: To verify that there is network connectivity between you and the database you can try `telnet xxxxxx 1234` (or `nc xxxxxx 1234`, where `xxxxxx` and `1234` are the service hostname and port, respectively.