# DB2 connectivity from Python - ibm_db.connect running continuously

Tags: python, db2

I have been searching for an answer for this for hours, but unfortunately the closest thing I can find is 1 unanswered question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431649/db2-connectivity-from-python-ibm-db-connect-time-out-latency) is a similar issue, but it unfortunately did not have a resolution.

I had a working connection to a IBM DB2 database, but the web console was erroring out, so I was forced to delete the instance and make a new one. I changed nothing regarding the code to connect other than the values used to connect. When I changed these values the ibm_db.connect function runs continuously. There are no output errors as I have left it running for 10 minutes and nothing happens at all. I do change the values to force an error and it will error out saying the values are not correct. I have no clue what the problem is as I have no information to go off of. My only thought is the SSL could have something to do with it.

```
dsn_driver = connection_data['dsn_driver']
dsn_database = connection_data['dsn_database']
dsn_hostname = connection_data['dsn_hostname']
dsn_port = connection_data['dsn_port']
dsn_protocol = connection_data['dsn_protocol']
dsn_uid = connection_data['dsn_uid']
dsn_pwd = connection_data['dsn_pwd']

dsn = (
    "DRIVER={0};"
    "DATABASE={1};"
    "HOSTNAME={2};"
    "PORT={3};"
    "PROTOCOL={4};"
    "UID={5};"
    "PWD={6};").format(dsn_driver, dsn_database, dsn_hostname,
                       dsn_port, dsn_protocol, dsn_uid, dsn_pwd)

try:
    connection = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
    print("Connected to database: ", dsn_database,
          "as user: ", dsn_uid, "on host: ", dsn_hostname)
    return connection

except:
    print("Unable to connect: ", ibm_db.conn_errormsg())
```

The breakpoint is at `connection = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")`

This data is loaded from a local JSON file with the following values (except for sensitive information).

```
{
    "dsn_driver": "{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}",
    "dsn_database":"BLUDB",
    "dsn_hostname": "hostname",
    "dsn_port": "port",
    "dsn_protocol": "TCPIP",
    "dsn_uid": "uid",
    "dsn_pwd": "pwd"
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of, but since nothing outputs I unfortunately do not know where to start. If someone has experience with this please let me know.

Thank you.

Edit: I did end up getting this error message returned from the ibm_db.connect method

```
Unable to connect:  [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific err SQLCODE=-30081054", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

Comment: Are you saying you've inserted a debugger breakpoint on that line? Have you tried "stepping into" the `ibm_db.connect` function to see what's happening in that library?

Comment: That is correct, I worked through it on the debugger and found that is where it wasn't continuing. I stepped into the `ibm_db.connect`, but nothing happened :/

Comment: Can you connect using jdbc, using the same connection details? python uses CLI driver not jdbc. Your IP connection details may be incorrect, or you have a firewall blocking the port somewhere along the path.  Your question shows you are __not__ using SSL, so if you thought otherwise then your connection string is likely incorrect.

Comment: Just a hunch: Are you using VSCode? There's an awful little debugging option that you may need to disable to trace 3rd-party code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56038698/235992 That may resolve "nothing happened".

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points for clarification:

1. When you say "the ibm_db.connect function runs continuously" do you mean you see the CPU spinning or just that the python process doesn't progress past the connect?
2. What type of database are you connecting to? DB2 LUW or z/OS?
3. Have you tried to make sure that the connectivity is still working? i.e. did you try the suggestion from the other linked post?  This:

To verify that there is network connectivity between you and the database you can try telnet xxxxxx 1234 (or nc xxxxxx 1234, where xxxxxx and 1234 are the service hostname and port, respectively

From a debugging point of view I'd be looking at the logs of the intervening processes:

1. Db2 Connect log if you are using it
2. DB2 target logs
3. TCPIP and z/OS Connect address spaces if z/os. BAQ region ? (not sure if that would just be my site)
4. Firewall - I know that you had a working connection but always best to check the obvious as well

As you've pointed out, without an error message it's hard to know where to start

Comment: 1. It runs continuously as in it continues to try to connect, but never actually connects or errors out.
2. It is a DB2 database.
3. I unfortunately do not know how to check that. If you happen to have any direction on that it would be much appreciated.

I tried to make sure it wasn't the firewall to allow the port, but didn't see any change.

Comment: Sounds like it is a unix DB2 LUW database. Inthat case I'd check out the db2diag.log files at the target to see if there are any messages coming out there as a starting point just to see if the connect string is hitting the database. Apps dont normally continually try to connect - they will normally wait for a response - is your app buring CPU cycles or just waiting ?

Comment: Shame, I have no solution just confirmation of the volatile problem.

I've just tried using Jupyter Notebook to manage my DB2 servers which are remote ones.
Jupyter's kernel crashed on all my trials.
Then I tried it directly from ipython3 using ibm_db a couple of times. Only once did it seem to connect but the assigned conn object was a basic python object, definitely not a connection.
Using ibm_db2_dbi it connected for the 3rd run after a long time, a lot longer than I can connect via Squirrel, DB2 CLI or Perl.
There's nothing related in db2diag.log at server side.